# How to do this in Visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to do the "a++" and "b++" in Visual basic?

What is the another codes for there in Vb?

The names there are just example.

```
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        {
            if (ans1.Text == "James") 
            {
                a++;
            }
            else
            {
                b++;
            }
            if (ans2.Text == "Ryan")
            {
                a++;
            }
            else
            {
                b++;
            }
            if (ans3.Text == "Mac")
            {
                a++;
            }
            else
            {
                b++;
            }
            t1.Text = a.ToString();
            t2.Text = b.ToString(); 
        }
```

Comment: The code in your question is C#, are you looking for conversion to VB.net? Don't really understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
a += 1
b += 1
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
DIM a as integer = 0
DIM b as integer = 0

If ans1.Text = "James" Then
    a += 1
Else
    b += 1
End If
If ans2.Text = "Ryan" Then
    a += 1
Else
    b += 1
End If
If ans3.Text = "Mac" Then
    a += 1
Else
    b += 1
End If
t1.Text = a.ToString()
t2.Text = b.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question has already been answered but I think it would be useful to see how you could simplify your code:

```
Dim correctAnswers As Integer = 0
Dim totalQuestions As Integer = 3'you need to modify this is you add more questions

'increment the number of correct answers for each one we find
correctAnswers += If(ans1.text = "James", 1, 0)
correctAnswers += If(ans2.text = "Ryan", 1, 0)
correctAnswers += If(ans3.text = "Mac", 1, 0)

'show the number of correct and incorrect answers
t1.Text = correctAnswers.ToString()
t2.Text = (totalQuestions - correctAnswers).ToString() 'show the number of incorrect questions
```

Comment: `If(ans2.text, "Ryan", 1, 0)` <---- Did you mean `If(ans2.text = "Ryan", 1, 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Neither the postfix nor prefix `++` are defined in Visual Basic.

Your only realistic option is to use `a = a + 1` (or, in later BASICs, `a += 1`) instead (note the lack of a `;` for a statement terminator). But note that this will not evaluate to the *previous* value of `a` and the entire construct is not an *expression* in the C / C++ sense. You could build a function to mimic `a++` but that would be too obfuscating.